# Set list of Identity roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a model view model like this:

```
public class ApplicationRoleViewModel
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> RolesToUser { set; get; }


    public class SelectListItem
    {
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Role Name")]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to create a list from this view model to set in select list so I try:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAvailableUserRoles()
{
    var roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();

    var vm = new ApplicationRoleViewModel();

    vm.RolesToUser = roles.Select(a =>  new ApplicationRoleViewModel.SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = a.Id,
        Text = a.Name
    }).Tolist()

    return Ok(vm);
}
```

But I get error:

> 'ApplicationRoleViewModel.SelectListItem' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Value'

View:

```
<form asp-controller="security" asp-action="GetAvailableUserRoles" method="get">

    <h4>Assign role to user</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="@Model.RolesToUser">
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>

</form>
```

In view I get error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: You have a nested class called `SelectListItem` within `ApplicationRoleViewModel` but you seem to be trying to use the [`SelectListItem` framework class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlistitem?view=aspnetcore-2.1) - you need to tell the compiler that's the class you want to use, perhaps by qualifying the name explicitly.

Comment: How can I specify class? I try changing List to : `public List<Roles> RolesToUser {  set;get; }` then mi nested class `public class Roles{...}` but I get same result @stuartd

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I create list of list item as:

```
 List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> item = roles.ConvertAll(a =>
            {
                return new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = a.Id.ToString(),
                    Value = a.Name.ToString(),
                };
            });
```